# Calculate the price of some bags of coffee. I am having difficulty incorporating the boxes in the final price

Tags: java

Your program is going to calculate the price of some bags of coffee.  You will first ask the user; how many bags of coffee do they want.   The price per bag is $5.50 each.  Your total price must also include the shipping of how many boxes this shipment will require.  There are three size shipping boxes available.  A large box can hold 20 bags, a medium box holds 10 bags, and a small box can hold up to 5 bags.  You cannot ship large or medium boxes that are not full. (however, small ones can have 1-5 bags in them) The price of shipping per box is large = $1.80, medium = $1.00, and small = $0.60.  You also give a discount on the coffee for large quantities.  Use the following chart to calculate the discount off of the coffee price (NOT off the shipping).
    0-24 bags - no discount     150-199 bags    - 20% discount
    25-49 bags – 5% discount        200-299 bags    - 25% discount
    50-99 bags – 10% discount       300 and up  - 30% discount
    100-149 bags – 15% discount

Discount is not to be used on the boxes.  Use if statements or a switch statement to get this done.

I have tried so many different things the past few days that I'm starting to scramble my thoughts. When my operation is complete, I get a total amount of $0.00. I need some direction as to how I incorporate the different boxes, if I need to show the price in the total for multiple different boxes as well. Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;//for Scanner
import java.text.DecimalFormat;//for proper decimal places


class Discount {
   public static void main ( String [] args) {


      String message;
      message = "Welcome to my program! Please input the amount of bags you need.";
      System.out.println(message);

      final double COFFEE_BAG_PRICE_PER = 5.50;
      final double LARGE_BOX_PRICE_PER = 1.80;
      final double MEDIUM_BOX_PRICE_PER = 1.00;
      final double SMALL_BOX_PRICE_PER = .60;
      int largebox;
      int mediumbox;
      double discountPercentage;
      double boxes = 0;

      Scanner coffeeBags;
      coffeeBags = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter the amount of coffee bags you want to purchase: ");

      int bags = coffeeBags.nextInt();// amount of bags

      System.out.println("Your total is: " + ((((discountPercentage)*(bags)) + ((boxes)*(bags)))));

   }
   public static double discount (int bags ) {

      final double COFFEE_BAG_PRICE_PER = 5.50;


      double total = bags * COFFEE_BAG_PRICE_PER;//number of bags times the amount of bags
      double amount = 0;
      if (bags<25){
         amount = total;//no discount on a purchase with less than 25 bags ordered.
      }

      else if (bags<50)

      amount = total - (total*(.05));

      else if (bags<100)

      amount = total - (total*(.10));

      else if (bags<150)

      amount = total - (total*(.15));

      else if (bags<200)

      amount = total - (total*(.20));

      else if (bags<300)

      amount = total - (total*(.25));

      else

      amount = total - (total*(.30));// if ordered 300 or more, overall discount is 30%.

      return amount; //returns value after the discount is applied.
   }

     public static double boxes (int bags) {

      double amount = 0;

      while (bags > 0){

         if (bags >= 20){
            bags -= 20;
            amount += 1.80;//adds 1.80 to cost for a large box
         }

         else if (bags >= 10){
            bags -= 10;
            amount += 1.00;//adds 1 to cost for a medium box
         }

         else if (bags >= 5){
            bags -= 5;
            amount += 0.60;//adds .60 to cost for a small box
         }

         else{
            amount += 0.60;
            bags = 0;
         }

   }

      return amount;

      }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call boxes and discount?

Comment: Your "constants" such as `SMALL_BOX_PRICE_PER` should be declared outside the `main` on the class level with `private static final double` so they can be accessed from any method.  Also you need to actually call the methods with `boxes(bags)` and `discount(bags)`, you never actually use them.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a few errors:

1) You're not calling your method `discount(int bags)` from your main method, so that logic is not even used.

2) This is your line:

```
  System.out.println("Your total is: " + ((((discountPercentage)*(bags)) + ((boxes)*(bags)))));
```

But `discountPercentage` is not initialized, therefore, you should have a compilation error right now. And `boxes` is initialized with 0.

Comment: `discountPercentage` is never initialized/set and has no default value because it is a local variable and not a class field (class fields have default values).  If you attempt to print something like `double value;`, it will be a compliation problem.  I don't know how he is even running it with no value for it.

Comment: @Nexevis `> javac -classpath .:/run_dir/junit-4.12.jar -d . Main.java
Main.java:29: error: variable discountPercentage might not have been initialized
      System.out.println("Your total is: " + ((((discountPercentage)*(bags)) + ((boxes)*(bags)))));
                                                 ^
1 error
compiler exit status 1` Yeah, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You never used any of the static methods discount and boxes:
I didn't go through all the steps but seems you need to **replace the following line**

```
System.out.println("Your total is: " + ((((discountPercentage)*(bags)) + ((boxes)*(bags)))));
```

**by this line:**

```
System.out.println("Your total is: " + (discount(bags) + boxes(bags)));
```

And you don't need any of these variables.

```
      final double COFFEE_BAG_PRICE_PER = 5.50;
      final double LARGE_BOX_PRICE_PER = 1.80;
      final double MEDIUM_BOX_PRICE_PER = 1.00;
      final double SMALL_BOX_PRICE_PER = .60;
      int largebox;
      int mediumbox;
      double discountPercentage;
      double boxes = 0;
```

At the end you need to close the variable coffeeBags.

```
coffeeBags.close();
```

**Program runs in my computer.**